# Reduction Formulae (Integration)

Tags: integration

I've noticed that some reduction formulae are defined for values above a certain value, but can still be used to solve to integrals below that value. Take the example: $$ I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sin^n x \ dx = \frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}, n\geq2 $$

Let's suppose we wanted to find $I_6$

$$I_6 = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sin^6 x \ dx = \frac{5}{6}I_4=\frac{15}{24}I_2 $$ The formula says it's only valid for $n\geq2$ but going down to $I_0$ will still yield the correct result. I have done other examples, which have a restriction on $n$ but it still works for all $n$. Why is there a restriction on $n$?

Comment: the recurion gives the correct result for $I_0$? i doubt that

Comment: If $n<2$ it is not the same integrand is it?

Comment: $I_0$ is trivially $\pi/6$ but the rhs of your recursion obviously diverges for this paricular $n$

Comment: @StubbornAtom nope